# how to change text color hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I change the text color when I hover on a `<li>` with what I have now I have to over over the text.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/EU4cz/

HTML

```
<nav id="NAv" >
<ul>
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Employment</a></li>
<li><a href="">Benefits</a></li>
<li><a href="">Forms</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Css:

```
nav#NAv
{
  width:192px;
  background:#FFF;
  padding:0px;
}

nav#NAv a
{
  color:#18819c;
}

nav#NAv ul li
{ 
  height: 30px;
  width: 192px;
  margin: 5px 0px -5px -10px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px;
  border-bottom:2px solid #c9dce1;
}

nav#NAv ul li:hover 
{
  background:#0f7691; 
  color:#FFF;
}
nav#NAv ul li a:hover 
{
  color:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: Searching SO with 'how to change text color hover' get 1'072 results!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display:block;` and `height:100%;` to your `nav#NAv a` links:

```
nav#NAv a {
    color:#18819c;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EU4cz/1/)**

Links are inline by default, and by making them block and increasing the height, they will take up the space of the list item.